# Prepend to all filenames in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, prepend

The goal is to prepend text to every file name in a specific directory using its path. I don't want this to apply to just the current directory, but would work no matter where you are in the file tree. This is what I have:

```
for f in `ls path/*`
do 
    mv "&f" "x$f"
done
```

Instead of moving it to the same path with a new filename with the x in front, it attempts to move it to x/path (which gives an error obviously), and I can't seem to find anything on how to get the x just in front of the filename to effectively rename the file with x in front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rely on both `basename` and `dirname` commands:

```
 for i in path/*; do 
   mv "$i" "$(dirname "$i")/x$(basename "$i")"
 done
```

Or with bash parameter expansion:

```
for i in path/*; do 
  mv "$i" "${i%/*}/x${i##*/}"
done
```

Both commands add a `x` before the filename.

Comment: I put a testfile in the target directory to test and this removed/moved the testfile to an unknown location and created a file named x in the directory above the target directory

Comment: @CassidyCantrell I added a quote in the resulting filename. Please retry. If it stills doesn't work, please use `set -x` before running the command to see what it actually does.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I was using your i variable and not keeping it consistent with my f variables. This did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: The latter won't work if you are more than one dir deep (`path/foo/*` or if you use an absolute path.

Comment: @PesaThe You're right! I added the `%` to match the end of the string.

Comment: Won't work either. `%\/` matches `/` at the end of the string, not the rightmost `/`.

Comment: The `dirname` solution works better for current directory, for example. But nice one anyway :)